# SCIF intrusion by members of Congress

Tags: united-states, congress

Having some tangential experience with Sensitive Compartmented Information Facilities ([SCIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitive_Compartmented_Information_Facility)) and how seriously they are taken, I was shocked to hear that one was stormed in Congress by people carrying cell-phones.

Wikipedia defines a SCIF thusly:

> A Sensitive Compartmented Information Facility (SCIF; pronounced "skiff"), in British and United States military, national security/national defense and intelligence parlance, is an enclosed area within a building that is used to process Sensitive Compartmented Information (SCI) types of classified information.

As noted in [this article](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2019/10/republicans-storm-ultra-secure-scif-some-with-cellphones-blazing/) "... bringing phones into the secure area was a potential felony."

Is it correct that is it a felony to bring cell phones into such a secure area in the normal case?

I have found this document which describes standards around SCIF construction and management: [TECHNICAL SPECIFICATIONS FOR CONSTRUCTION AND MANAGEMENT OF SENSITIVE COMPARTMENTED INFORMATION FACILITIES](https://fas.org/irp/dni/icd/ics-705-ts.pdf)

I've not, as of yet, been able to find anything that explains what laws apply to these facilities and what ramifications there are for violators.

According [this article](https://www.justsecurity.org/66699/gop-storming-of-secure-facility-for-impeachment-proceedings-an-explainer/):

> ...while there are criminal statutes that would otherwise come into play here, it is not useful to discuss them here because, under the Speech or Debate Clause of the U.S. Constitution, a member of Congress cannot be criminally prosecuted for an action he or she takes as part of the individual’s legislative work.

There is no reference to which criminal statutes would apply, however.

Is this assessment correct that such actions could not be criminally prosecuted were they illegal?

[image]

The above image is purported to be from the incident.

Alex Mooney made a recording *inside the SCIF* that he then published on Twitter [here](https://twitter.com/RepAlexMooney/status/1187063885372841989?s=20).

Comment: Please spell out SCIF and explain what an SCIF is/

Comment: As far as I have seen on the news, the members gave their phones to aides, before being in the actual room with the sensitive info.

Comment: @ohwilleke SCIF is just a term congress uses for the area where they allow members to look at classified or sensitive info in private.

Comment: @Putvi Good edit.

Comment: @Putvi A SCIF is not specific to congress.  See link in the question: [TECHNICAL SPECIFICATIONS FOR CONSTRUCTION AND MANAGEMENT OF SENSITIVE COMPARTMENTED INFORMATION FACILITIES](https://fas.org/irp/dni/icd/ics-705-ts.pdf)

Comment: @Putvi "As far as I have seen on the news, the members gave their phones to aides, before being in the actual room with the sensitive info"  Incorrect.  The phones were collected by another member of congress from within the room and removed.  The fact that they brought phones in is not in question.

Comment: @JimmyJames more than one person does not go into the room at the same time, so it is in question. A member of congress on the news said they went to the SCIF, demanded to be let in, then a Dem member complained and they handed his assistants their phones.

Comment: @Putvi I have no idea where you are getting this.  Here's a video if you want to see for yourself.  Multiple people walking in while recording video: https://twitter.com/ScottThuman/status/1187023336255250433

Comment: @Putvi I've also seen some reports that some of these members initially refused to turn over their devices but I haven't seen that reported widely.

Comment: @Putvi You can listen to a recording Representative Alex Mooney made inside the SCIF and then published on Twitter here: https://twitter.com/RepAlexMooney/status/1187063885372841989?s=20

Comment: The sign in the photo says it all, "Cameras and recording devices prohibited without proper authorization." This means that proper authorization to bring Personal Electronic Devices (PEDs) is available. While it's easiest to state that no PEDs are permitted, that rule, like many usually begins with, "No, but..."

Comment: @DaveD From the technical specs and other documents, I believe that some special recording devices are (rarely) allowed but not cell phones.

Comment: @JimmyJames - here's a document that outlines how a PED, including a cell phone, can be brought into a SCIF. It's always going to be on a case-by-case basis. https://fas.org/irp/dni/icpm/2005-700-1-att1.pdf

Comment: @DaveD OK sure but it's pretty clear that there was no approval in this case, right?  I don't think anyone has credibly claimed that the policy was followed.

Comment: @JimmyJames - I have no idea if it was followed or not. It's just supportive of the argument that carrying a PED into a SCIF is not, by definition, a felony. There have been too many edits to the original question for me to deconstruct how it was phrased in the beginning but the document I provided showed that there are permissible methods to take cell phones into a SCIF. I'm not making any other claims about this instance.

Comment: @DaveD I'm not sure this logic follows.  There are exceptions to most any law for practical reasons.  If it's simply a semantic argument, I can update the question to include "without proper authorization".  And it's certain that was not in play here.

Answer (score 3):

It is unlikely that it is a felony to enter a SCIF with a cell phone (or thumb drive, Apple Watch, fitbit etc). The felony clout comes from the [non-disclosure agreement](https://www.dni.gov/files/NCSC/documents/Regulations/FORM%204414_Rev_12-2013_fillable.pdf) which references Sections 793, 794, 798, 952 of Title 18 and Section 783(b) Title of Title 50 -- gathering and disclosing information is a felony. A non-exhaustive reading of the relevant chapters of the US Code does not provide any evidence of a felony charge relatable to phones and SCIFs.

There is a [federal law against knowingly entering or remaining](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1752) in any restricted building or grounds without lawful authority to do so. This includes

> knowingly, and with the intent to impede or disrupt the orderly
>   conduct of Government business or official functions, obstructs or
>   impedes ingress or egress to or from any restricted building or
>   grounds

which protects against intrusion of

> a building or grounds so restricted in conjunction with an event
>   designated as a special event of national significance

The courts would almost certainly hold the recent event to be a non-justiciable political matter.

Comment: Thanks.  One thing I've come across when searching on this is the [claim](https://www.fastcompany.com/90421321/gop-storming-house-impeachment-hearings-wasnt-just-a-dumb-stunt-it-was-a-security-breach) "If someone enters a military SCIF with a potential listening device, it’s considered treason." I have no idea if this is true or how I would determine the veracity of the claim. I've considered creating a skeptics question but I'm not sure it meets the 'notable claim' standard.  This wasn't a military SCIF but I'm curious about this claim.

Comment: @JimmyJames Generally that would be some form of espionage if they did it for the purpose of recording information illegally, not treason.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Wouldn't espionage against the US by a US citizen be treason i.e. aid and comfort to the enemy?

Comment: Well, I've been there when a thumb drive was accidentally brought in, and although there was a kerfuffle, there was no arrest or anything like that.

Comment: @user6726 In a military SCIF or some other context?  That was what was seemed dubious to me about this claim about treason, that there would be an assumption that there was intent and the goal of that intent.

Comment: @JimmyJames Treason has an extremely specific definition: you have to either wage war on the US or adhere to its enemies, giving them aid and comfort. Giving aid and comfort isn’t treason unless you specifically do it to aid the enemies of the US. Even then, it’s questionable whether any country can be an enemy for treason unless the US has declared war against them. The Rosenbergs weren’t tried for treason despite giving nuclear secrets to the Soviets.

Answer (score 1):

The main protection for a SCIF is that it has a air gap to prevent data from being leaked. It is assumed that the computers in the SCIF could be compromised, so the air gap is essential.

It has been proven that the flickering from an LED light for a hard disk drive can hijacked to transmit encoded data. That flickering is not perceptible by the human eye, but can be picked up by cell phone cameras. https://www.pcworld.com/article/3173371/a-hard-drives-led-light-can-be-used-to-covertly-leak-data.html

Bringing cell phones into a SCIF certainly has the potential to be a treasonous act.